# RISC-V 64 bit IMC adding compressed instruction suport

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

I have a task and I am making research about how I can design a RISC-V 64 bit IMC chip. In design step of the compressed instruction , I notice that opcode of some instructions and func3 part are same. For example in figure below FLW and LD instruction opcode = 00 and func3=011 part is same and both of them CL type instruction. It is so easy in I type and M type instruction but in compressed set all instructions are 16 bit  and I did not understand how I distunguish this instruction from each other.

[image]

This problem created the following question, since the instructions that write 64 bit and 32 bit (with the same opcodes and func3 parts) in the table are performing the same process, will those labeled 64bit be used in 64 bit processors and will those labeled 32it be used in 32? Is such thinking correct or can risc-64 be used in compressed instructions labeled 32bit in IMC (next to the table)?

[image]

Comment: As you noticed, the *(RV32)* vs. *(RV64/128)* seems to be saying that the same opcode means one thing in compressed RV32 and a different thing in compressed RV64 mode.  That seems normal; 64-bit operations are likely to be more common in 64-bit mode, so you'd rather have a compact instruction for it and have to use a 4-byte instruction to do a 32-bit shift or load.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant.  For 64bit processor in risc v, 64C type and 32C type instructions are both 16 bits.actually the difference between riscv32 and riscv64 just means that the processor registers and data memory are 32 or 64. In both of them instruction memory is 32 bits. So when distinguishing these two compressed instructions, let's not forget that both are 16 bits. Both 64c type and 32c type instructions are required to be supported on a 64-bit processor. I haven't completed the part of how to distinguish between these two types of commands while coding.

Comment: Right, but a CPU is either an RV32 or an RV64 CPU.  (Or maybe capable of running in either mode.)  Which of those modes you're in can determine how a 2-byte instruction is decoded.  It would make a lot of sense that an RV64 would want to re-purpose some of the limited coding-space for instructions that are more common in 64-bit mode, instead of having the same machine-code across all modes.  (Something that would be fine without compressed instructions.)

Comment: You need to know the base ISA, then that determines the compressed instruction set.  Note that even without the compressed extension, the same instruction in RV32 may operate differently in RV64.  For  example, the 32-bit loads in RV32 sign extend in RV64, while adds in RV32 simply operate on 64-bits, while new ADDW is provided on RV64 for 32-bit addition.

Comment: Basically, there appears to be no design goal that code written to RV32 will run properly directly on RV64 processor without an explicit 32-bit mode/capability.